# gnu emacs ebrowse doesn't work well when viewing some large codebase

Tags: c++, emacs

My emacs version is 27.
I think `ebrowse` is native c++ parser bundled with emacs, so i spent some time learning it.
I first use it to parse `LevelDB`, and it worked quite good, but when parsing `folly`, problems occured.
My command to generate BROWSE file is :

```
find  -E .  \( -regex ".*\.(h|cpp)" ! -regex ".*Test.*\.(h|cpp)" ! -regex ".*/test/.*\.(h|cpp)" \)  | ebrowse
```

The terminal has some error message:
[image]
Then i open the file and look up the `IOBuf` class:
[image]
Its parsing result is wrong(i think), i couln't even enter the `IOBuf` class

Was there anything wrong i made? Thanks!

Comment: `ebrowse` is very simple and just doesn't understand everything.

Comment: @nega: yeah! After searching for some other tools, i've noticed this point. Now i use u-ctags, maybe lsp-mode in the future. Sorry not to update this question.

Comment: But i think ctags and ebrowse works in different field.